# compile problem C++

Tags: c++, exception, compilation, streambuf

Hey guys.
I need to compile some project.
I installed Visual C++ 6.0 + Microsoft Platform SDK 2003 from there
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en#requirements

I also added SDK paths under Tools->Options->Directories and moved them to top.

But I am still getting this errors when compiling...

> c:\users\admin\downloads\microsoft visual c++ 6.0 standard edition\vc98\include\new(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'exception': No such file or directory

And

> c:\users\admin\downloads\microsoft visual c++ 6.0 standard edition\vc98\include\ios(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'streambuf': No such file or directory

Anyone got some idea?

Comment: First of all: Why are you using such an old compiler? Visual C++ 6.0 has only rudimentary stl support (at least according to the standard). Is it an option to install the latest Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Comment: Avoid VC6 if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to download an old compiler version like VC6 would be you need to rebuild a project developed for that exact version.  But this code clearly isn't.

Try it with the latest Visual C++, [which is 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP) as Andre commented.

Note: The Feb 2003 SDK, the last one compatible with VC6, is available on MSDN.

> Platform SDK - February 2003 Edition (English) 325 (MB)
>
> File Name: en_platformsdk_win2003.exe
>
> Date Published (UTC): 4/4/2003 9:25:00 PM
>
> Last Updated (UTC): 8/25/2005 9:36:39 PM
>
> SHA1: 33E0434F63EFFC0A04B3401D992AE4478E4C80E7    ISO/CRC: A519A771
>
> Available to Levels: MSDN OS (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Pro (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (Empower); MSDN OS (Retail); Developer AA; VS Pro with MSDN (Retail); MSDN Universal (Retail); VSTS Team Suite (VL); VSTS Architecture (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (MPN); VSTS Test (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (MPN); MSDN Universal (VL); VSTS Database (VL); VS Pro with MSDN Premium (Retail); VSTS Test (Retail); VSTS Development (Retail); VSTS Architecture (Retail); VSTS Team Suite (Retail); VSTS Database (Retail); BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Pro with MSDN Embedded (Retail); VS Pro with MSDN Embedded (VL); VS Test Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (VL); VS Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Test Pro with MSDN (Retail); MSDN Essentials; VS Premium with MSDN (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail); MSDN for Action Pack; VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN); VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE);

Platform SDKs have been free for quite a few years now, some links are provided in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/83205c43-ef46-447d-ae54-92bbeb543c38) and seem to still be live.

Comment: Because people who coded it, coded it in VC6 and I was told to compile it there...
Cheers

Comment: @pwnu91: Have you installed all the VC6 service packs?  But I consider it quite unlikely that the `<exception>` header would be used in VC6-era code, people avoided templates since VC6 didn't handle them in the way required by the standard.

Comment: I downloaded cab files from that link but im on x64 and when i run setup64 i get **The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running**
Neither 32 bit works as expected :(

Comment: @pwnu91: Did you run the batch file first?

Comment: @pwnu91: And you tried right-click, "Run As Administrator"?  Back in Feb 2003, I think 64-bit Windows meant Itanium architecture, not x86_64, so use the installer named "setup" not "setup64".

Comment: I get **The image file C:\SDK\setup64.exe is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine**
And yes i run setup.exe and also tried to fix it with "Compatibility Wizard" but nothing works...
EDIT: I tried with Win 98 compatibility mode and it just opened webpage but no setup wizard was launched...

Comment: I kinda remember the platform sdk installer being HTML driven for a while... see where that "web page" leads you.

Comment: @Ben
Yes when I run it in IE it asked me to install ActiveX onctrol and i allowed etc then i got some error message that control failed to run blabla...
I doubt its possible to install it on 7 :'(

Comment: @pwnu91 -- yuck.  How about using a virtual machine to run VC6 tools?  http://superuser.com/questions/149238/how-to-run-ms-c-6-0-on-windows-7

Comment: Well I am already using vmware...should i search for 98 somewhere and emulate or what?

Comment: @pwnu91: That superuser question/answer suggested Win2k, and I agree.  It's much more stable than Win9x, and uses a lot less resources than XP.

Comment: OK guys just letting you know that i solved problem by installing windows 2000 and ran SDK installer from there and it compiled OK :)
Thanks again @Ben Voigt

Answer (score 4):

According to [the page you linked to](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en#requirements), the SDK you linked to was published 5/2/2005.

"This SDK does not support working with Microsoft Visual C/C++®, 6.0 as support for VC 6.0 has ended. The last SDK that will work with VC 6.0 is the February 2003 Edition"

More generally, just read the documentation of things.

If your machine is too old to use the free Visual Studio Express 10.0, then I suggest using Code::Blocks IDE. Which you can configure to use any compiler. Including, like, an earlier Visual C++ version bundled in an old SDK.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Ben: thanks. I've edited answer to include info that OP's SDK was published 5/2/2005. cheers,

Comment: So anyone got link to 2003 edition of SDK?
I wouldn't use it if i wouldnt be told too...its not my code...

Comment: @pwnu91: It's available to MSDN subscribers.  I'll add the information to my answer since it doesn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth are you using VC6? And if you use it, why with the standard library, for which it only has buggy support? Better download one of the current [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

That said, it looks as if your include path is missing something like: "`c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\stl\`" or wherever you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I find that with VC 6 I often need to add ".h" to the include file names. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

VC6 is from 1998, and before SP5 it didn't even get for loops correct. Don't use it, ever, it is the most standard uncompliant compiler that is still out there.