# Why does "cout" keep giving me error C1083?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was using Visual C++ 6.0 just now, and I keep getting this error:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'streambuf': No such file or directory

My code is just a simple hello world program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<<"Hello World.";
    return 1;
}
```

Then I went and checked my INCLUDE folder and found a file called STREAMBF, but the compiler was looking for STREAMBUF. Notice that the file that is present is missing the U, between the B and the F. This was from a good copy of VC++6.0, directly from the actual CD, not a pirated copy. So there should be all the files needed. But it appears that a file is missing! Is this MS being stupid again, and yet making another big mistake, and forgetting to include an important file on their CDs? I'd hate to think that every single CD for VC++6.0 that was pressed that came out of MS factories had this problem. And I know that it is a missing file, not just a misnamed file, as renaming STREAMBF to STREAMBUF just led to more errors.

Anybody know where I can find a copy of the file STREAMBUF? Or am I just overlooking something here? Is this exact error a known problem with running old copies of VC++ on modern OS's like Windows 7? Is it possible that the only reason that it's looking for STREAMBUF is that this is a newer file associated with Win7, and that if it was running in a different environment (an older OS), it would actually be looking for the correct file, STREAMBF? Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Is there any reason to use VC++6? This compiler's "interpretation" of the C++ standard is questionable. This error however looks like your installation is broken in some way. `streambuf` is a standard header that is included by `iostream`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887788/compile-problem-c

Comment: The Visual C++ 6.0 compiler is very old, and was released the same year that C++ was standardized, it might mean that it's standard library may not be totally standards compliant, including the header files. Try including e.g. `<iostream.h>` (the pre-standard name) and see if that works better.

Comment: I had to use that compiler about 15 years ago at a company and it was considered outdated *then*.

Comment: I don't think it's an accident. "STREAMBF" is 8 letters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg your suggestion doesn't work either. Now I'm getting the error:

Comment: C2871: 'std' : does not exist or is not a namespace

Comment: You get the new error because pre-standard didn't have any `std` namespace, so try again without the `using` directive (which you really shouldn't be having anyway).

Comment: Just grab [Visual Studio 2013 CE](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). When creating a new project, make sure it's a "Win32 Console Application" and you'll end up with a 100% native program without any overhead and with no dependency to the CLR (i.e. .Net Framework). Using a completely outdated compiler will make your learning experience even harder, simply due to the fact that you won't be able to use many snippets and might indeed learn wrong concepts or simply do things the wrong way to circumvent issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation is either broken, deprecated or interpretes your code in wrong way.
You should only use older compiles if you are trying to build project developed entirely for this version.

Try to compile same code with new compiler, if you want to use VS then you should look for Visual Studio Express 2013.

Your code does not have any errors.

Comment: Better is [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

Comment: Yes I know it's old. I'm using it to teach myself the C++ language. Besides, all the new versions of VC++ (like VS2013, etc) are based on .Net. Therefore anything they compile cannot be run on computers that do not have .Net. They are NOT classic C++ compilers. They are actually using a combination of C++ and .Net, so it's not really pure C++.

Comment: @BenHutchinson That's simply not true. Even with MSVC 2013 you're still able to build a native C++ executable which will **not** depend on .Net. You'll only get .Net code if you actually create a CLR project. The only dependency you might have to install is the MSVC Runtime (but only if you link it dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

For my win 10 installation of VC 6.0, I had the same problem ... fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'streambuf': No such file or directory
Replacing  with <iostream.h> does not solve the problem.
I have checked the header file installation folder (Program files\VS98\VC98\INCLUDE). For some (unknown) reason, some file names have been changed during installation. Restoring the original name has solved the problem, in my case, in example:
Turn STREAMBF into STREAMBUF, STDXCEPT into STDEXCEPT, XCEPTION into EXCEPTION, FCTIONAL into FUNCTIONAL.
Notice: other header file names might be wrong. I have listed above the file names wrong in my installation.
I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your program to, you should be able to see it okay.

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World.";
    return 1;
}
```

However,
your compiler is pretty old. You need to an upgrade.

- There are C++ compilers for Windows from Microsoft Express Visual Studios [Link and Info VS2013](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadVisualStudioExpress.aspx) to
- some other non-Microsoft like  [GCC for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/).
- If you don't have installation access there are some [portable c++ compilers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/).
- Finally there are some online compilers for simple test. [web based online compilers](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: I know it's old. I'm using it as a simple implementation of C++ to teach myself the C++ language. I normally use VB6 for writing programs, and I'm trying to broaden my knowledge of programming. I've heard that all the real programmers in software companies are using C++ to write their stuff (everything from video games, to database software, to software that processes scientific data, basically any software for the computer, that is written by professionals, is written in C++).

Comment: Sure good luck. But I believe you need to use newer version of C++, it will have more educational benefits for you. The changes are enormous so the old compilers might keep your progress troublesome. And for sure you won't get proper community support, which is dedicated mostly to newer versions.